# How to change mathjax's color and background

Tags: firefox, mathjax

Mathjax's formula looks like this on my firefox with [Blank Your Monitor + Easy Reading](https://addons.mozilla.org/zh-tw/firefox/addon/blank-your-monitor-easy-readin/).
[image: formula]
Is there any solution?

Comment: This looks like Wikipedia's image rendering, not MathJax. Are you logged into Wikipedia and have activated MathJax? I don't see a problem when trying that. But I do see this with the PNGs generated by Wikipedia (not using MathJax). The effect is due to the images being static PNGs with transparent background and black foreground (= the equation content). MathJax HTML-CSS output will inherit the styling from this Firefox extension just fine -- try it on mathjax.org or math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You're right. Mathjax works fine. I just created an account and activated MathJax.